# Array data not getting populated on JQgrid

Tags: jquery, arrays, jqgrid

I am very very new to jquery and I am trying to execute some program related to jqgrid.

Here is my code,

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.multiselect.css" />

    <script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<table id="grid"></table>
```

=====================================================================

```
var fd= [];
var sd = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
sd.push(48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN");
}

var ld=[sd];
alert(ld);

var data = ld;

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Blank', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60,
        sorttype: "int"},
    {
        name: 'thingy',
        index: 'thingy',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "date"},
    {
        name: 'blank',
        index: 'blank',
        width: 30},
    {
        name: 'number',
        index: 'number',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float"},
    {
        name: 'status',
        index: 'status',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float"}
                                                                ],
    multiselect: true,
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example"
});


var names = ["id", "thingy", "blank", "number", "status"];
var mydata = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    mydata[i] = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
}
```

Actually I tried above code with below static data, which is displaying 10 records correctly on my grid.

```
var data = [[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"],[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"]];
```

But when I try the same using dynamic array this way, I am getting only last record on my grid..

var fd= [];
    var sd = new Array();

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
sd.push(48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN");
}

var ld=[sd];
alert(ld);

var data = ld;
```

What is the mistake I am doing here, Can some one help?

Comment: It's very very bad example which you use. It is sure not what you want to display. Even HTML is bad. One should have `<table>` inside of `<body>` and not directly after `<head>`. Which version of jqGrid you need to use? **How looks the real data which you want to display? Which columns should have the grid based on the data?**

Comment: hi, this is the fiddle I am trying to execute,http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/stxfL/

Comment: its working fine with the dummy data ad above, but the only problem is with framing the dynamic data..

Comment: I've seen such code example before. It's the worst and the slowest example of usage jqGrid which you can find. I don't recommend to use it. Instead of creating empty grid and filling it using `addRowData` one should use `data: mydata, gridview: true` to *create* the grid with correct data. The items of data should have unique `id` property. I asked you multiple questions. Please answer there.